# Dependency issues with Eclipse and a maven multi module project

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, maven-3, m2e

I have a multi-module maven project made up of three sub-modules: **web**, **service** and **domain**. I use m2e and have managed to import the maven projects into Eclipse.

What's more, the **service** and **domain** projects are in the **web**'s java build path and the **domain** project is in the **service**'s java build path.

It is very strange because compilation errors are displayed which seem to indicate that for instance **service** does not see **domain**. However when I click on a class in error in eclipse, I can navigate to the **domain** class.

Furthermore, I can add the **web** project to the Tomcat server instance but the **web** project does not contain the other two projects.

Can anyone please help?

web pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.bignibou</groupId>
        <artifactId>bignibou</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bignibou</groupId>
    <artifactId>bignibou-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bignibou-web</name>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.tml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/WebContent</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warSourceExcludes>WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</warSourceExcludes>
                    <archiveClasses>false</archiveClasses>
                </configuration>
                -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bignibou</groupId>
            <artifactId>bignibou-domain</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bignibou</groupId>
            <artifactId>bignibou-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-beanvalidator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-spring</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.formos.tapestry</groupId> <artifactId>tapestry-testify</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0.2</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.formos.tapestry</groupId> 
            <artifactId>tapestry-xpath</artifactId> <version>1.0.1</version> <scope>test</scope> 
            </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

service pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.bignibou</groupId>
        <artifactId>bignibou</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bignibou</groupId>
    <artifactId>bignibou-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bignibou-service</name>

    <!-- Shared version number properties -->
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--
            Core utilities used by other modules.
            Define this if you use Spring Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Expression Language (depends on spring-core)
            Define this if you use Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core)
            Define this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, spring-beans)
            Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, spring-beans)
            This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection Container and is generally always defined
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, Quartz, and Freemarker integration
            Define this if you need any of these integrations
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-aop, spring-context)
            Define this if you use Spring Transactions or DAO Exception Hierarchy
            (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
            Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, and iBatis.
            (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
            Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans.
            (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
            Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and Portlet Environments
            (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
            Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and TestNG
            This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bignibou</groupId>
            <artifactId>bignibou-domain</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

domain pom.xlm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.bignibou</groupId>
        <artifactId>bignibou</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bignibou</groupId>
    <artifactId>bignibou-domain</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bignibou-domain</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eclipselink</id>
            <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

super pom.xlm:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bignibou</groupId>
    <artifactId>bignibou</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bignibou super pom</name>
    <modules>
        <module>domain</module>
        <module>service</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define domain and service modules inside the dependency management tag in super pom. So basically add following definition inside super pom:

```
     <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
           <dependency>
              <groupId>com.bignibou</groupId>
              <artifactId>bignibou-domain</artifactId>
              <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
              <groupId>com.bignibou</groupId>
              <artifactId>bignibou-service</artifactId>
              <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
           </dependency>
        <dependencies>
     </dependencyManagement>
```

After adding these definitions to the super pom, you will also have the chance to remove version numbers for these dependencies from module pom's.

Comment: Melihcelik: Thanks. I have done that. Do I need to reimport the maven project into eclipse afterwards?

Comment: Yes, re-import might also be necessary. I just realized that while trying to fix indentation, I deleted the closing tag for `dependencies` tag, I fixed it now. And I also added an extra information, too.

Comment: it is much better now because I see the domain and service wars in the Tomcat server. However, tomcat's console doesn't seem to indicate it is deploying the application: I get absolutely nothing related to my app on the console. Very strange indeed...

Comment: After performing a "clean module work directory" it deployed my app! Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't work with eclipses build paths.

Add the service and domain to the web pom.xml dependencies.
Add the domain to the pom.xml from your service.

After you set up the dependencies correctly m2e will configure the build paths correctly for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, the dependencies are already specified in the pom files...

Comment: Try an update project configuration for all your projects. Could you please post the 3 poms? Do a maven install on the 3 projects as well. Afterwards look into the generated war of the webprojects and check if the dependencies are included.

Comment: Yes after doing the "mvn install" I checked and noticed that the dependencies were there. However Eclipse's tomcat instance won't deploy the war (as per the console) but does display the web project in the server instance: very strange...

Comment: We are working with [MyEclipse](http://www.myecliseide.com) here. Its handling our Maven web projects well.

Comment: I cannot find an obvious error in the pom. As we war looks fine you probably have an deployment error. Are the dependencies showing up as maven dependencies in each module? Try a project clean as well. Another thing to try would be that you close the domain and service module after you did the install and check if its deploying your installed artifacts.

Comment: Regarding your point about a possible deployment error: I had a look at the console and cannot find anything related to my app: no logging info whatsoever! However, the web app appears under the server which puzzles me...

Comment: I did a clean module work directory and it now works! Thanks!